# How to show multiple attributes in the drop down list of React-Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, react-select

I am working on a project where I used React-Select as part of a form to create a multi-value input box for adding multiple contributors for a submission. Earlier I was using

```
valueKey="id" labelKey="name"
```

So, the drop down list was showing Names of the current users of the platform. Now I want that avatars(profile images) of those users should also appear against the names. I have already edited my api endpoint to get avatar link as well as part of response. I already tried making **name** as an array of actual name and avatar url

```
 id:key,name:[p[key].name, p[key].avatar]
```

but it shows name and avatar url as option, something like

NAMEhttps://*******/photo.jpg

So,firstly how can I show user image against his name in the drop down list rather than the actual url

And,Secondly when a user select that option it should only show name as selected option in the input box.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have you researched custom placeholders? [**Custom Placeholder, Option, Value, and Arrow Components**](http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/#react-select-10--value)

Comment: Not yet, But I will now  try that as well. Thanks for the suggestion.